# find and return Urls from Note column in table

Tags: string, sqlite, url, return, substring

I have a sqlite database with a column (Note) and this contains a variety of content.
Some rows have Urls in them and I want to get a list of these.

I can find them like this: 
SELECT SUBSTR(Note,'http') FROM PersonTable WHERE Note LIKE 'http%'

But this returns the whole string in the Note column when it finds a Url. What I want is to return only the URL nothing else.

I know this must be simple for anyone familiar with SQL but its new to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [`SUBSTR` function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr) expects its second parameter to be the start position; `'http'` will just be interpreted as `0`.

SQLite has no built-in function that would allow to find the end of the URL; you should split the returned column value in your program.

Comment: Thanks CL. So first things first - is there a query that will find all the rows with http in it, even those that dont begin with that?

Comment: That depends on how you decide to detect the end of the URL, and what language you are using.